# Creating Aliases/Redirects/Rewrite for Top-Level Redirects for Apache Servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a [personal and professional website](http://jdclark.org/), which serves two main purposes:

- The site’s first function is to provide information about myself for
  the general public (e.g. about me, contact info, CV/resume, etc.)
- The second function is to serve as a kind of “one-stop-shop” web app so I
  can access all of my essential resources from one central location
  (e.g. webmail, ISP control panel, admin settings, etc.)

I would like to create “top-level redirects” from my website to these key locations. My preferred method of doing this would be to create a series of simple PHP scripts – using so-called “cool URIs” – that will then send a simple HTTP redirect to the actual location of these resources.

**Example:**

File: `mail.php`

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/webmail');
?>
```

The desired effect is to be able to provide stable URIs for these resources: although the actual destinations themselves are very likely to change, they can always be referenced from 
“cool URIs” – ones that will never change – as Sir Tim Berners-Lee describes in his famous article, “*[Cool URIs Don’t Change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)*”.

However, in the interests of managing/maintaining the (already large number of) files in my root directory, I would be very grateful if someone could help me to set up the relevant directive(s)/rule(s) on my Apache server so that I can contain all of these PHP redirect scripts neatly in on sub-directory, yet still be able to reference them at the top level.

```
/ public_html
    |
    | –  / redirects
             |
             | – admin.php 
             | – mail.php
             | – [etc.]
```

In short, what I would like to know is this:
How can I configure Apache to treat the PHP file at `/redirects/mail.php` as `/mail.php`?

**Technical Restrictions:**
My website is running on a typical LAMP architecture. However, as I am currently using shared hosting, I *cannot* modify the `httpd.conf` file – I can only apply Apache directives with `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're effectively needing to just take any request for a php file in your site's root and pull it from under the /redirects/ sub-directory, then maybe try:

RewriteRule ^/(.+\.php)$ /redirects/$1 [NC]

Answer (score 1):

With mode rewrite installed and enable.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mail.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://youserver/redirects/mail.php
```